# Using Microsoft Store Services SDK in a converted desktop app

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-store-apps, desktop-bridge

I want to log custom events to the Store from my converted desktop (WPF using the desktop bridge project centennial) app.
Here is how to do this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/log-custom-events-for-dev-center

I installed the SDK, but unfortunately I cannot select the  "Microsoft Engagement Framework" reference for that as there is no "Universal Windows" section in the reference manager. How can I add this to my WPF project though?

Answer (score 1):

Add a UWP project to the solution.
Use the SDK in the new project.
Call into the new project using AppServices to have that project log the events.

Comment: It would be a great help, if you can provide a sample to open feedback hub. I searched over net, and it looks like api is not yet supported for bridge app.